# How to use a customized 404 page in Django CMS

Tags: django, django-cms

Django allows to use [customized error views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/views/#id1), but I would like to take advantage of the CMS and use one of his pages for displaying the error.

I have tried adding `handler404 = 'hotels.views.page_not_found_view'` to `urls.py`, and then rewrite the request in the view so it renders my error page:

```
from cms.views import details

def page_not_found_view(request):
    return details(request, 'page_not_found')
```

But no luck so far, the app cannot find the path. Does somebody know an easy way to achieve this without using redirections?

Comment: could you detail the error you've got ?

Comment: Have you published a page with the slug `page_not_found`? You need the page so that `details()` can find the page.